# Windows Forms Binding: is there an event similar to DataBindingComplete, but fired when ALL bindings are completed?

Tags: c#, winforms, events, data-binding, mvvm

I need to change a certain DataGridView's property (a DataSourceUpdateMode for one of its binding) only when ALL of its initial data bindings are completed.

I tried subscribing to the "DataBindingComplete" event, but it's fired too many times (one or more time for each binding associated to the control); what I need is a more global "AllDataBindingsComplete" event, fired when the control is ready to be displayed to the user.

As a temporary workaround, I'm using the MouseDown event (I've assumed that when the user is able to click the control, it means that the control is displayed... :) and the events I'm playing with - SelectionChanged - are fired after the MouseDown):

```
    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Binding selectedItemsBinding = this.DataBindings["SelectedItems"];
        if (selectedItemsBinding != null)
        {
            selectedItemsBinding.DataSourceUpdateMode = DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged;
        }

        base.OnMouseDown(e);
    }
```

It works, but it smells like an ugly hack A LOT (and it's called too many times, only one time is enough for my needs).

Is there a better way?

(yes, I'm trying to adopt MVVM in a Windows Forms project, and I've added a bindable "SelectedItems" property to the DataGridView...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I've done at the [Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms) *form* level, and may be improvised down to just the control(s) you want, is to subclass the Windows Forms baseclass into my own. Then, in its constructor, attach an extra event call to the `Load()` event.

So when everything *else* is *completely loaded*, only THEN will it hit my custom method (of the subclass). Since it is the bottom of the call-stack chain being attached to the event queue, I know it's last and everything else is done...  Here's a snippet of the concept.

```
public class MyForm : Form
{
    public MyForm()
    {
        this.Load += AfterEverythingElseLoaded;
    }

    private void AfterEverythingElseLoaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Do my own things here...
    }
}
```

This concept can be applied to the `Init()` function too if that's more appropriate for your control... Let everything else within it get initialized(), then do you the "AfterInitialized()" function.

Comment: I'd like to keep my control as more "container agnostic" as possible, handling all this stuff internally. Thanks anyways, I tried to obtain a reference to the parent form from the control constructor, but this.FindForm() doesn't always return a not-null form (even trying calling it inside a ParentChanged handler). For now, I'm using the first "Enter" event, which is better than "MouseDown" event, since it's called even with keyboard navigation)

Comment: ... in the end I've followed your suggestion (the Load event), wrapping the DataGridView inside an user control (which has the Load event), and moving the custom bindable properties to it, instead of subclassing. :)