# How to determine when the user control is fully loaded and shown?

Tags: c#, winforms, events, user-controls, load

There were already a few similar questions on stackoverflow, but I haven't found the answer

I have an application that consists of several tab pages. On one of them I'm loading a list of a few dozen user controls at a time. Currently I'm doing it in Load event and because of that I have a small delay before this page is loaded. What I want to do is to make UI more responsive and fill the list after the page is fully loaded. Is there any way to track when the user control has fully loaded it's content?

VisibleChanged doesn't help too, because it fires before any other child control is shown. That causes some ugly visual effects when some of the child controls are still not visible when I'm starting to load control list.

**EDIT**

To make it more clear. I have some child controls on a page container and I have a list of custom controls I'm trying to load later. The problem with two approaches described in several answers below is that when I'm starting to load controls they do not let other child controls on the container to be shown and that is why I have those ugly effects (and I'm doing that with BackgroundWorker, but anyway it has to interact with the main thread to add controls to the list)

Comment: [DRapp's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6654780/199364), used correctly, should solve this problem. See my comment on that answer for more details.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to make the UI more responsive, you should post yourself a message (`Control.BeginInvoke`), do one operation, post yourself another message.  Then every time you do anything, the next step will get queued after all user messages, so user actions will get processed promptly.

One really nifty approach is to use `yield return` and let the compiler take care of all the closures logic:

```
IEnumerable AsyncLoadUI()
{
    var p = new Panel();
    Controls.Add(p);
    yield return null;

    for( int i = 0; i < 50; ++i ) {
        var txt = new TextBox();
        p.Controls.Add(txt);
        yield return null;
    }
}

override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    IEnumerator tasks = AsyncLoadUI().GetEnumerator();
    MethodInvoker msg = null;
    msg = delegate { if (tasks.MoveNext()) BeginInvoke(msg); };
    msg();
}
```

Comment: Wow, took me a few reads to get what was going on here. Very clever, but also potentially confusing for future maintainers of the code. It would be overkill for just adding a bunch of textboxes as in your example - I expect the OP has something a bit more time-consuming going on in the Load code.

Comment: @Mark: The appeal of this method is that it works with very complex code as well, as easy to use as DoEvents, but doesn't require a nested event loop the way DoEvents does.

Comment: @Mark Heat, yes I'm loading a list of custom controls. @Ben Voigt this snippet works good, but it doesn't solve the problem completely. The code I put in each task requires time. When those tasks are processed, they do not let all other child controls to be shown because each task makes interaction with UI thread anyway. Thanks for the answer, its really creative =)

Comment: This is also the way the Form.Shown event is implemented.  Which would be another way to get this behavior.

Comment: @username: This gives you a simple way to break up tasks into subtasks that each require very little time.  If you have a big chunk of processing that doesn't involve the UI, like a database query, use a backgroundworker for that.

Comment: Is this code works for C# .net4.0? The VS says that `tasks` doesnt have a member `MoveNext` and it also says the use of unassigned variable `msg`. Help.

Comment: @GaryNg: Yeah, there were a couple small issues with the example.  `tasks` needs to have type `IEnumerator` not `IEnumerable`.  And `msg` needs to be initialized.

Comment: @Ben Voigt : Thanks a lot! It works! When adding 1000 controls to the winform, the code works perfectly, but when i minimize and maximize the winform, the winform became laggy and unresponsive, how can i solve this?

Comment: @GaryNg: I don't think there is a solution other than not using 1000s of windows.  You can use windowless controls, or a virtual grid system.  I guess you could intercept when the form is being minimized, and set all the controls to hidden.  Then use a technique like this to show them again later.  But you can't use this technique to make minimization fast, since the minimize action will still be processed synchronously.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: i'm adding over 1000's of picturebox in the winform. will hidding all the picturebox when winform is minimized take time?and what is the virtual grid system?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [my solution offered to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6228655/windows-forms-binding-is-there-an-event-similar-to-databindingcomplete-but-fire/6230307#6230307).  They had a very similar issue.  Wait until EVERYTHING finished its loading before doing a certain action, but not every time a form necessarily became "activated" or "shown".  It involves attaching to the Load handler of your outermost control of interest.  In your case, the tabbed page, but the example solution I provided was at the FORM level.

Comment: Your solution is very elegant and simple.  +1

Comment: In OP's case, there are **two problems mingled together**. **First problem** is starting the load early. DRapp's answer should solve that, **if** you put his code at the correct place. **Don't** put his code on the user control itself. Instead, put it on whatever control is containing those user controls. Then it won't start until after that container's `Load` has returned - at which time all the children will also be loaded.

Comment: **Second problem** is that there is something "slow" in the code for loading the user control. That logic should be moved off the UI thread. Use any technique for starting a Background task, but **don't wait for the result** from your main thread. Rather, use `BeginInvoke` on the containing control, to do the final display step. **Most importantly, whatever it is that is slow** (e.g. loading an image file and preparing - but not adding to display - a bitmap from it) must be done **BEFORE** that `BeginInvoke`, while you are still on a background thread.

Answer (score 1):

If the loading of this list incurs a small delay then doing this load on the UI thread will **always** make the form unresponsive no matter what event you do it in - changing this to be done after the form has loaded then it will just make the form unresponsive and visible as opposed to just causing a delay before the form is shown.

If there is no way to speed up the loading of the list then you will probably need to change your form loading logic so that the "heavy lifting" is instead done in a background thread so that the form remains responsive while the list is being populated.  You should be aware that multithreaded code is more difficult to understand and when done incorrectly can produce bugs that are intermittant and difficult to debug and so you should definitely try to speed up your existing code first.  That said if you can't speed up your list loading and the delay is unacceptable then there is not really any alternative.

If you do choose to load your list asynchronously (in a background thread) then the idea is to start a background thread (usually via a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) ) that does the hard work of preparing a list of items to be added - when this has finished (or failed) the form / list box is updated with the supplied list of items.

You should be able to find plenty of resources on how to do this on the internet that will cover this in more detail.

Comment: Yep, I'm loading them in another thread, but that still requires syncronization with the UI thread and as a result I'm loading them before any other child control have shown

Comment: @username I'm not sure that I understand - why bother loading this list in a background thread if you synchronise this call during the load method?  Perhaps a small snippet of your code would help?

Comment: I'm already loading them with the BackgroundWorker. The problem is when to start. When I'm starting on VisibleChanged there are still some child controls that are not visible. Loading controls requires syncronization with UI thread and doesn't let any other children controls to load instantly

Comment: @username I would start the worker during Load and have the list box display as "Loading..." (or similar) until the worker has completed - you need to make sure that your form logic can handle this but it means that there is no need for synchronisation.

Comment: Your last proposition doesn't solve the problem with other child controls. I can put a Loading.. image or smth similar on my control list and hide it after backgroundworker is completed, but their loading still causes those visual effects when other child controls continue to change their visibility one after another. (Unless this progress label will hide them too, but then it is not very helpful). Of course background worker takes a large amount of work for control creation but I still have to add them in UI thread

Comment: Thanks for the answer, one way or another, it seems that I will solve it with something simple like progress bar

Comment: @username It sounds like your problems are more design related - determining what the form should look like while the various controls are loading.  You seem to already have a fairly good grasp of the technical details.