# How to wait until a usercontrol is fully loaded in WPF

Tags: wpf, user-controls, wait

If I were to use Canvas.Children.Add(userControl); to make the user control appear in the window, how do I make my event handler wait until a user control is loaded completely before executing the next lines?

Comment: What's your definition of "fully loaded"? Is it sufficient when the control fires its Loaded event?

Comment: the good question is why you have to wait for it to be loaded ? normally you don't have to...there is a conception problem !

Comment: I kindly disagree that this question is a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6652933/how-to-determine-when-the-user-control-is-fully-loaded-and-shown) since it concerns _WPF_, and the linked one concerns _WinForms_, so the accepted answer does not apply to this question. Although I'm pretty sure this kind of question was already asked on SO, this particular mark is inaccurate and misleading.

Comment: @Grx70 is right.